# Laravel 5 - Storing in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am fairly new to Laravel 5. I managed to populate forms from the database and update them and also store values in the database.

Now I am trying to store values into the database without collecting them from a view type form. It is an internal value that I want to store. (Eg: a special id generated in the controller) Hence using 
    `Input::all()` 
doesn't seem to work.
Is there any other way to store such values in the database?

Comment: Can you show how are you doing it now with the form. Is it the same model?

Comment: @PawelBieszczad Currently I am showing the values using a view and when the user clicks "ok" button, I would like to store these values in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the User model that comes with Laravel. You can create a new user and persist it to the database doing the following:

```
$user = new \App\User;
$user->name = 'John Doe';
$user->password = bcrypt('yourPassword');
$user->email = 'john@doe.com';
$user->save();
```

Comment: I would like to populate the "user" model using values being displayed in the view via another model say profile. So what I would like to do is : 
$user = new \App\User;
$user->name = $profile->name;
$user->email = $profile->email;
$user->save();

Comment: But the issue I am facing is - When i try to use profile->name, it is empty so database does not get populated at all.

Comment: You can send the id of the profile via a hidden input. When the user clicks the OK button, you just do $profile = Profile::findOfFail(id) and then populate the user field with that info.

Comment: thank you that worked. Though this can at best be a temporary fix. Any other long term secure solution? The problem is that the 'profile' model becomes empty when it is passed to the 'user' controller. The relationship between my User model and Profile model is one is to one.

Comment: I need to see your code but, why would it be a temporary fix? If you send data to the view and you need to re-send it from the view to the server, yo need something like this.